# Could unsetting variables in php affect caching?

Tags: php, caching, memcached, apc, varnish

Maybe this is a stupid question, but at the end of my pages i set all of the variables to null and then unset them, for performance, even though, i know, it probably has little to no effect on performance, but even so, would that have any effect on any caching modules, such as , varnish, apc, or memcached?

Comment: They will be all deallocated at the end of the script anyway. Let PHP clean up for you :)

Comment: The only time you should unset variables is when you're going to need the memory for a ram-intensive section of your script, or it's a long running script and they won't be needed later on. Otherwise PHP will clean up for you when the script exits.

Comment: thanks so much for the input, wish you guys woouldve set it as an answer, i appreciate all of the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't affect anything except for (maybe) the garbage collection. Look [here](http://lampzone.wordpress.com/2010/03/26/how-does-apc-work/) at how APC works. Most other caching plugins work the same way.

You'll notice that cachers like APC (memcached has nothing to do with this question, by the way - and neither does Varnish) still parse all PHP. The only thing unsetting variables may do is cause the garbage collector to kick in. If the GC kicks in, you may see a slow-down (and then, a speed-up). With that said, though, it's not very deterministic. Usually PHP is pretty good about garbage collection, so you shouldn't worry about it unless you're trying to emulate some sort of RAII behavior.

Varnish is an HTTP accelerator (that has nothing to do with PHP). memcached is a distributed memory-based information store (which also has nothing to do with PHP's inner workings).

Comment: right on, thanks for the help, well I thought there was a module, that absically caches compiled php code, so that it does not have to be compiled everytime it is run, any idea what that might be?

Comment: I think there's some settings on some cachers where that may be possible. Either way, even if the final product is cached, the unsetting of variables won't affect it.